Set grid frequency for plot
I have a very simple code that plots points by coordinates (x, y)
def separate_file(coordinates):
    new_document_x, new_document_y = zip(*coordinates)
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
    plt.plot(new_document_x, new_document_y, "r", marker='.', linestyle='None')
    plt.show()

print(separate_file(
[[184, 60], [33, 76], [33, 128], [33, 180], [327, 149], [33, 325], [399, 598], [221, 625]]
))

output

But I would like to add a grid to this graph. On the x-axis with a frequency of 100, and on the y-axis with a frequency of 200.

I tried some options from the internet but didn't get the desired result. Please tell me how can I achieve this

"but didn't get the desired result". What result did you get? Share the code your tried and explain why the results aren't right.

You could play with the Axis ticks to make your custom grid (same logic described here) :
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def separate_file(coo, xoff=100, yoff=200):
    def mloc(axis, mul):
        axis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(mul))
        axis.set_minor_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(mul/2))
        axis.set_minor_formatter(plt.ScalarFormatter())
        
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    ax.scatter(*zip(*coo), c="blue", s=10, zorder=2)

    # grid
    mloc(ax.xaxis, xoff)
    mloc(ax.yaxis, yoff)
    ax.tick_params(which="both", length=3)
    ax.grid(which="major", c="orange", lw=1.5)

    plt.show()


